# Can not add com.github.dcendents.android-maven

Tags: android, maven, bintray

I tried to upload my code to bintry so that I can connect it to jcenter but the problem occurs when I add this line to my library build.gradle:

`apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'`

gradle can not be build, what did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was using gradle 2.4.

I don't know why but by downgrading gradle to 2.2.1 it get solved.
Just go to `File` then `Project Settings` and write in gradle field `2.2.1`.

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks. what an strange behavior from gradle